# Is it possible to run IBM Domino docker container created in linux on MacOS?

Tags: macos, docker, lotus-domino

Since there is no docker image of IBM Domino available yet I am assuming that I need to create a linux VM to built a docker container of IBM Domino, using what Ulrich has describe here (https://www.eknori.de/2017-08-20/domino-on-docker/). Can I then run this docker container on Mac OS ? Or do still need to use a linux VM to run this docker container ?

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/faq/

*"Docker defines a format for bundling an application and all its dependencies into a single object called a container. This container can be transferred to any Docker-enabled machine. The container can be executed there with the guarantee that the execution environment exposed to the application is the same in development, testing, and production. LXC implements process sandboxing, which is an important pre-requisite for portable deployment, but is not sufficient for portable deployment. If you sent me a copy of your application installed in a custom LXC configuration, it would almost certainly not run on my machine the way it does on yours. The app you sent me is tied to your machine’s specific configuration: networking, storage, logging, etc. Docker defines an abstraction for these machine-specific settings. The exact same Docker container can run - unchanged - on many different machines, with many different configurations."*

To me it sounds like that would be possible. But why not go ahead and try it, then report back here?

Update: See this article from IBM: [https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22013200&myns=swglotus&mynp=OCSSKTMJ&mync=E&cm_sp=swglotus-*-OCSSKTMJ-*-E](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22013200&myns=swglotus&mynp=OCSSKTMJ&mync=E&cm_sp=swglotus-_-OCSSKTMJ-_-E)